# Hammer JS Multi-Touch Gesture Event listening not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-touch, hammer.js

Any ideas why this code, using [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) to listen to multi-touch gesture events, is not working?

It is quite similar to one of [the site's examples of using Hammer](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started).

However, when I swipe over these elements, the alerts do not fire.

```
var settings_panel = $('.settings');
var hammertime = Hammer(settings_panel).on("swipedown", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("settings swiped down!");
});
var dataCard = $('.dataCard');
var hammerLeft = Hammer(dataCard).on("swipeleft", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("dataCard swiped left");
});
var hammerRight = Hammer(dataCard).on("swiperight", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("dataCard swiped right");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code, working perfectly on Chrome while emulating touch events. Make sure you're including [jquery.hammer.js](https://raw.github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/dist/jquery.hammer.js) so it can play well with jQuery and not just [hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/dist/hammer.js)

Comment: It is not working for me. Here is a live URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcYUctMllHMFoxeTA/KE_home.html Each of those white rectangle cards are of .dataCard and should fire an alert on x-axis swipe. But don't on my Nexus 7 running chrome.

Comment: Also, how do you emulate touch events in chrome?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events

Comment: Does the URL I commented work for you? It doesn't for me. It does not work on multi-touch nor does it work in chrome with multi-touch enabled for me.

Comment: Chrome Windows 7 works well. but Chrome Android does not work. several swipe action, 1 swipe event fired.